# How to alter a function in a contributed module?

Tags: 7

I am using a module [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) in my website.

I have a taxonomy in which I have some parent terms and there children terms, I am getting two select list with this module. In one select list I am getting all parent terms, and the module is filtering the second select list as per the parent selected, showing children terms of parent term selected in select list 1.

I need to add some condition to the values I am getting in the select lists to alter this function ***shs_json_term_get_children*** using custom module.

The function declaration in the module is:

> function shs_json_term_get_children($vid, $parent = array(), $settings
>   = array()) {}

So I tried using:

> function hook_shs_json_term_get_children_alter($vid, $parent =
>   array(), $settings = array()) {}

and

> function hook_shs_json_term_get_children_alter(&$vid, $parent =
>   array(), $settings = array()) {}

but neither worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only alter the functionality the module exposes using hooks defined by that module, and you cannot alter just any function defined in the module. For instance, `shs_json_term_get_children` is just a callback, and you cannot alter it.

The SHS module defines several hooks that are listed in the `shs.api.php` file. For instance, there is a hook called `hook_shs_term_get_children_alter`, that allows you to modify the list of terms displayed to the user: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/shs/tree/shs.api.php?h=7.x-1.x#n73

```
/**
 * Alter the list of terms within a level of the term hierarchy.
 *
 * @param array $terms
 *   List of terms displayed to the user (single hierarchy level).
 * @param array $alter_options
 *   - vid: ID of vocabulary or field name
 *   - parent: ID of parent term
 *   - settings: Additional settings (for example "language", etc.,)
 */
function hook_shs_term_get_children_alter(&$terms, &$alter_options) {
}
```

In your module, you would need to implement that hook like that:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_shs_term_get_children_alter(&$terms, &$alter_options) {
  // Your code here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some wrong assumptions:

- `shs_json_term_get_children()` is not a hook, but a simple callback
- Even if it were a hook, implementing a similar hook doesn't override any other hook, except in the case of alter hooks, which are those hooks whose names end with `_alter`
- Implementations of hooks are not named like `hook_shs_json_term_get_children_alter()` if *hook* is not the machine name of the module implementing it

As said in the answer for [Is there any way to validate taxonomy terms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97154/is-there-any-way-to-validate-taxonomy-terms) the module defines `shs_json_term_get_children()` as callback using the following code.

```
$callbacks = array(
    'shs_json_term_get_children' => array(
      'callback' => 'shs_json_term_get_children',
      'arguments' => array(
        'vid' => 'is_numeric',
        'parent' => 'is_array',
        'settings' => 'is_array',
      ),
    ),
    'shs_json_term_add' => array(
      'callback' => 'shs_json_term_add',
      'arguments' => array(
        'vid' => 'is_numeric',
        'parent' => 'is_numeric',
        'name' => 'is_string',
      ),
    ),
  );
// Let other modules add some more callbacks and alter the existing. (!)
drupal_alter('shs_json_callbacks', $callbacks);
```

So, if you need to completely override that callback (i.e. not rely on the values returned from that callback), you can implement code like the following.

```
function mymodule_json_callbacks(&$callbacks) {
  $callbacks['shs_json_term_get_children']['callback'] = 'mymodule_json_term_get_children';
}
```

(Replace *mymodule* with the machine name of the module you are implementing.)

Your callback will receive the same arguments received from the original callback.

If, instead, you just want (for example) add a few terms to the ones returned from `shs_json_term_get_children()`, or remove a few terms from the ones returned from that function, you implement `hook_shs_term_get_children_alter()`.

```
function mymodule_shs_term_get_children_alter(&$terms, &$alter_options) {
  // Alter $terms, or $alter_options.
}
```